# Should we start putting Diablo 3 lore questions into a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

With Diablo 3 firing on all cylinders, players are progressing at vastly different rates. There are starting to be more and more questions about the lore from people who have finished the game. The problem is, a lot of these questions could be considered spoilers for those who have not finished. With that in mind...

**Should we start catergorizing lore questions into a specific tag that can be hidden by those not wanting to see spoilers?**

I have started tagging new lore questions that pop up with "diablo-3-lore" in the meantime so you all can see what I'm driving at.

Answer (score 4):

Use [diablo-3-story](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-story) or [diablo-3-lore](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-lore) ... [story](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story) is only another tag that will eventually be marked for burnation.

Comment: Does `[diablo-3] [diablo-3-story]` really have an advantage over `[diablo-3] [story]`?  The former is repetitive, and if it only had `[diablo-3-story]` then it wouldn't be properly categorized.

Comment: @MatthewRead It's the same conversation about meta tags that Mark linked to in the comments below.  I wouldn't want to see [tag:story] be a top tag any more than [tag:pc]

Comment: Ahh, yes right.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment on the `story` tag and the discussion under @Raven Dreamer's post.

I have already been using the story tag a few times to mark Diablo 3 questions that are unrelated to gameplay, assuming it is a valid tag (and I personally do think it is). However if its deprecated, what other options would I have to do the same? After all, Tyrael's powers or Zoltan Kulle's actions are unrelated to the actual game but are (afaik) valid questions.

Also, I have another question related to other classifications of gameplay-unrelated questions - see this one:

[What does the "Balor" affix mean?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72144/what-does-the-balor-affix-mean)

This is again nothing to do with gameplay, but can't be labeled as a story either - so how should it be tagged?

Also, my 2c - having `diablo-3-story` means a story tag for each game; vs just `story` and either `diablo-3` or *{actual game tag}*. I strongly favor a single `story` tag or equivalent (lore, game-universe or w/e)

Comment: I think the point is that [story] is hard to use as a sorting tag (because it will give you questions about lore in every game that has decent plot), where as [game-title-story] will only give you questions on that game, making it a useful tag?

Comment: @Gwen: Instead of a tag population explosion, maybe look at my FR request [Make 'Related' links prioritize questions matching *all* tags](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/make-related-links-prioritize-questions-matching-all-tags)

Answer (score 0):

We already have a tag for lore questions. It's the [story](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story) tag.

Comment: okay, thanks for letting me know, still fairly new here.

Comment: @Tater596 Also, we used to have a [tag:spoiler] tag for this purpose (ignoring), and we removed it because we determined that it was not a good solution nor was it an intended use of our tagging system for various reasons. You can see [the discussion here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/spoiler-alert-spoiler-dies) if you would like to read more about the reasoning behind this.

Comment: [tag:story] is a crap tag, and you're ignoring previous consensus ([here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3800/have-we-not-been-clear-enough-that-meta-tags-are-a-bad-thing/3838#3838) and [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/should-we-allow-tags-for-a-specific-class-in-rpg-games)) that rejects the notion that we should have non-game specific don't-call-them-meta tags.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Uh, no. *You* are ignoring the previous consensus that story is a valid tag. ([here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/2700/336)) I'll admit that it was much better represented before Jeff nuked it, however.(200 or so?)

Comment: @RavenDreamer Besides being almost a year old (compared to the two discussions I linked being much more recent), it says nothing about story being a good tag that we should use. You even made a case that similar tags like lore should be removed. I recognize that at one point there was a fascination with the junk non-game specific tags here, but that died a long time ago.

Comment: I made a point that similar tags should be *combined*, not removed. And I'm still not convinced that `story` is a junk tag.